# combine two columns like zip - best pattern

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have two columns with some boxes, e.g. survey, calendar, twitter etc. that have unknown height. I want to combine them into only one column like zip if user has smaller screen - take first box from first column, then first box from second column, second box from first column ...

Is there any good pattern how to do it properly, ideally with minimum javascript code that operates on DOM model?

Comment: Maybe you provide a visual example?

Comment: Provide a sample of your code and some kind of example to explain what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I created [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/justincavery/full/KsjHa) that demonstrated running 2 columns within the same container using column counts.

Using this CSS you can spread your content across two columns at a particular width by setting it within a media query.

```
.columns { 
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Saf3, Chrome*/
  -webkit-column-gap: 4%; /* Saf3, Chrome*/
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* FF3.5+ */
  -moz-column-gap: 4%; /* FF3.5+ */
  column-count: 2; /* Opera 11+*/
  column-gap: 4%; /* Opera 11+*/
}
```